# boost::bind function with its input argument error

Tags: c++, boost, bind, boost-thread

I am trying to do multithreading by `boost::bind`. But, I got error:

> src/model.cpp:225:   instantiated from here
>   /boost_1_45_0v/include/boost/bind/mem_fn.hpp:333: error: pointer to member type `void (Model::)(taskDataSPType&)` incompatible with object type `taskDataSPT1ype`
>   make: *** [model.o] Error 1

Here is my code:

```
void Model::runTask(taskDataSPType& myTask)
{}

taskDataSPType myTask;

fifo_pool tp(thread_num);

for (int i = 0 ; i < totalTaskNum ; +i)
{
    taskQueue.wait_and_pop(myTask, i);
    myTask.taskID = i ;
    // run the typical iterations 
    tp.schedule(boost::bind(&Model::runTask, &myTask));
}
tp.wait();
```

In another header file, I have :

```
typedef struct taskDataSPT1ype taskDataSPType;

struct taskDataSPT1ype
{
    int taskID;
    int startNode;
    int endNode;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

`Model::runTask` is (presumably) a non-static member function. That means you *cannot* call it without an instance of the class. `boost::bind` knows this, and therefore it expects the first parameter to be a `Model` of some form, or a derived class thereof. So your `bind` takes two parameters: the `Model` and the function argument `taskDataSPType&`.

Also, your argument is a reference, but you seem to be attaching a pointer. That's not going to work either. You may need to use `boost::ref`, as follows:

```
tp.schedule(boost::bind(&Model::runTask, /*Some Model Instance*/,
    boost::ref(myTask)));
```

Comment: No need to presume, the definition of `Model::runTask` is there and you are correct. +1

Answer (score 0):

`&Model::runTask` is a member function, and as such it has an extra implicit argument `this`. So in your particular case, you want to bind it with two arguments: an instance of `Model` and a `taskDataSPType` object. Note that if one wants to pass references with `bind` it has to use `boost::ref` or `boost::cref`.